# how can change multi select board color using jquery validation in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

I am trying this,

```js
if ($(this).hasClass('select2') == true && $(this).hasClass('required') == true) {
  var idName = $(this)[0].id;
  var e = document.getElementById(idName);
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (strUser == 0) {
    alert("Please select a user");
    document.getElementById(idName).style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById(idName).style.borderWidth = "1px";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddltest1" class="form-control select2 required" multiple="multiple" tabindex="2">
  <option value="0">--select--</option>
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
  <option value="4">test4</option>
</select>
```

how can change the border colour of select dropdown?
it's not working...

Comment: `$(this).hasClass('select2')` is not javascript. That's jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You are mix between jquery and javascript.
Change some code to work around as

`var idName = $(this)[0].id;` change to `var idName = $('#ddltest1').attr('id');`

`$(this)` for current tag, but you did not show what event is handling.

Change `var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` to `$('#ddltest1').val()` to get selected value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('#ddltest1').hasClass('select2') == true && $('#ddltest1').hasClass('required') == true) {
 
   var idName = $('#ddltest1').attr('id');
 
  var e = document.getElementById(idName);
  var strUser = $('#ddltest1').val();
  if (strUser == 0) {
    alert("Please select a user");
    document.getElementById(idName).style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById(idName).style.borderWidth = "1px";
  }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddltest1" class="form-control select2 required" multiple="multiple" tabindex="2">
  <option value="0">--select--</option>
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
  <option value="4">test4</option>
</select>
```